# retrieve next value in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop here:

```
foreach($decode_rewardsAPIResponse->rewardUnlockStatus as $key=>$value){
   echo $value->rewardID;
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is to be able to get the next item in the loop's rewardID. I have tried using `next($value->rewardID)` but had no luck.

Here is a sample of the data i'm receiving:

```
{"currentMilestone":2,"rewardUnlockStatus":[{"rewardID":1,"stepsRequired":0,"unlockedForUser":true},{"rewardID":2,"stepsRequired":0,"unlockedForUser":true},{"rewardID":3,"stepsRequired":2200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":4,"stepsRequired":5200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":5,"stepsRequired":8200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":6,"stepsRequired":11200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":7,"stepsRequired":14200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":8,"stepsRequired":17200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":9,"stepsRequired":20200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":10,"stepsRequired":23200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":11,"stepsRequired":26200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":12,"stepsRequired":29200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":13,"stepsRequired":32200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":14,"stepsRequired":35200,"unlockedForUser":false},{"rewardID":15,"stepsRequired":38200,"unlockedForUser":false}]}
```

Comment: That data looks a bit like a JSON encoded string, though it certainly could be something else. If so, then please dump the structure after decoding it. What do you get?

Comment: Have a look to json_decode PHP function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Apologies, data updated